# Entity framework use of Database Views

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, view

Currently in our system we have performance issues with some slow performing queries.

One suggestion is to create a database view which we can index.

What are people's thoughts about using database views in general, is it another item that's needs to be maintained. Is it necessary? Is it better to create smaller queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A view is good, however if you make changes to your DB you will have to create a new view.

Comment: It should also be noted that if you have complex joins in your queries then that would explain the performance issues.